# Seaborn pairplot: data must have variance to compute a kernel density estimate

Tags: python, seaborn, kernel-density

I am trying to run this code below:

```py
print(); print('Scatter Matrix Plot')
sns.pairplot(dataset, hue = 'Protein', diag_kind="kde")
plt.show()
```

where dataset is data read from a csv using `dataset = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ',', names = col_names)`.

I do not get a terminating error when I run this code, but instead I get a warning, which is "`data must have variance to compute a kernel density estimate`" and none of the plots have a kde curve through them. I have looked this up and found that this might be due to repeating data, but the only instances where solutions are documented are ones using the `kdeplot()` function, so I am at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what type of data `Protein` is, I guess from its name that it is categorical. In this case there might be a value in `Protein` that appears only once, thus no variance can't be computed for the respective data.

Look for `Protein`-values for which there is only one unique value in any column:

```
only_one_by_prot = (dataset
                    .groupby("Protein")
                    .nunique() = 1
                   ).any(axis=1)
```

To get a list of these `Protein` values do:

```
proteins_with_too_little_data = (
    only_one_by_prot[only_one_by_prot]
    .index.values
)
```

To filter out these `Protein`-values from `dataset`:

```
dataset.query("Protein not in @proteins_with_too_little_data")
```

I don't assume that your `Protein` column has continuous numeric values, however that usually doesn't work as well in seaborns `hue` as it is very likely that some number appears only once. In this case, bin the data, e.g. with [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).